# How to connect c# application on two systems having one database, both applications are same

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, networking

Any one help me to solve this problem of my project.

I just want to run an app on two systems by sharing a single database.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to indicate what problem you are having.

Comment: I Create an application having its own database in C#. Now i want to run that application on two systems of my shop linked with one database may be you called it centralized.

Answer (score 0):

Install a database server and use a connection string for both.
By the way it really depends on your app architecture but in most cases the above solution works.

Comment: Sir, can you please elaborate?

Comment: In a simple way you have two computers that your app installed on. Then you install Database on one of them or on any other server that both computers can access to (like an online database). Now set the connection string for both systems to connect the same Database.

Comment: The problem with broad questions is that they lead to answers that are book length or the answers leave out things like concurancy.